# Stringify Data from a WebSource without using IE for VBA

Tags: java, vba, stringify

My Page source looks like below:
[Page Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR7PR.jpg)
The Page output looks like
[Browser Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIamk.jpg)

I can capture the data in a string using the IE Control for VBA but was looking to do this with MSXML.
Any suggestions as to how this might be accomplished in VBA or am I stuck with IE.

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing how the content get populated.  Java tag though?

Comment: I believe Java. not positive.

Comment: Maybe javascript would be relevant, but likely not Java.  Also looks like the page has some Flash on it?

Comment: Yes but the data source im grabbing is listed as plain html according to the limited info I have. I believe the frame in question is being generated.

Comment: If I look at the DATA element I see just a simple listing of each line item  inside <b> tag.  With the data following and a line break <br>. I can easily pull this apart with IE but was hoping to get rid of it in favor of msxml. Help in this reguard is what i need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to say without seeing the script which populates the `<data />` div

Comment: I could provide the output, from inspect element, it is called state.js and i do not have access to the actual script.  The Output is a single line of data broker by <b> and <br> tags

Comment: Any script executed when the page loads will be viewable via your browser's Developer Tools